# Files aren't found by commands until I ls them

Tags: macos, osx-lion, cups

When I try to add printers using lpadmin (after unzipping the correct PPD's enclosing .gz archive) I often receive the error:

"Unable to open PPD file [x] - No such file or directory."

But when I navigate to /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/ and ls, the PPD I was trying to use is right there. So I hit up-cursor a few times to the lpadmin in history, and reissue the command verbatim...and it works.

This is replicable on numerous Macs, both in 10.6 and 10.7. It's as if the ls command "convinces" lpadmin that the PPD actually exists. I can't figure out if this is filesystem lag (buffering), a Terminal problem, or something else.

Comment: What happens to you is not *"until you 'ls' them"*, it's rather *"until you 'cd to their directory', or?"*....

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the path when you specify the PPD file?  I.e. you need to use something like:

```
lpadmin [...] -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/SomePrinter.ppd
```

If you only specify `-P SomePrinter.ppd`, it won't work until/unless you `cd` to the folder the PPD is in...

Comment: Thanks guys. I assumed (yeah, yeah) that lpadmin knew to look in /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-P` (PPD) flag to `lpadmin` requires the (either absolute or relative) path to the PPD. **IF**  and ***ONLY*** if you are in `/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/` the simple name of the PPD suffices.

Alternatively, you can use the `-m` (model) flag to `lpadmin`, which doesn't require a path, but the model name of your printer instead.